# What is the difference between Line-Replaceable Unit (LRU) and Line Replaceable Modules (LRM)?

Tags: aircraft-performance, avionics, engineer

i am studying Line-Replaceable Unit (LRU) and Line Replaceable Modules (LRM) but do not know the difference.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between Line-Replaceable Unit (LRU) and Integrated Modular Avionics (IMA)?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/17077/19)

Comment: @DeltaLima Your related answer would answer this question if it clarified that LRMs are the replaceable components of the IMA.

Comment: @Gerry Thanks for the hint, I didn't realise I had answered that question. I've added the part about the LRMs. We can close this as a duplicate